# TypeScript: Enforce distinction between type alias with common primitive type

Tags: typescript, alias

I'm interested to know if there's a convenient way to have TypeScript distinguish primitive types so that they are regarded as different types, without the use of boxing (ie via an interface)?

For instance, suppose I have the following:

```
type Foo = number;
type Bar = number;

function logFoo(foo:Foo) {
    console.log(foo);
}

const barValue:Bar = 1;
const fooValue:Foo = 2;

logFoo(fooValue);
logFoo(barValue);    // <-- I'd like this to cause a compilation error
```

I understand that type aliases allow naming/renaming of primitive types, type unions, etc, and that the alias itself isn't strictly a "new type", which is why the code above still compiles.

Is there any mechanism or language feature that would enable me to achieve what I require?

Comment: You can't. That violates duck typing.

Comment: Thanks @artem - wasn't aware of the "Flavoring vs. Branding" terminology as described here: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2018/01/15/typescript-flexible-nominal-typing/

Comment: Thanks for the link.